# Why is it eating a letter every other run?

Tags: terminal

When I run this code on the terminal:

```
for ((j=0;j<29;j++)); do
echo "ffmpeg -r 288 -i \""./out "$j"/out.%04d.jpg"\" -f gif ./gifs/"$j".gif;"
done
```

And I copy and paste the output on the terminal, it works every other run, the rest it eats at least a letter. Example:

```
~/Desktop$ mpeg -r 288 -i "./out 27/out.%04d.jpg" -f gif ./gifs/27.gif;
```

Instead of:

```
~/Desktop$ ffmpeg -r 288 -i "./out 28/out.%04d.jpg" -f gif ./gifs/28.gif;
```

Why is that?

Comment: which OS are you using? terminal would suggest mac os. Correct?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that, it is Ubuntu.

Comment: Am I right if I guess that the "copy and paste" you mentioned involves a windows or mac machine as well?

Comment: what kind of EOL char do you use when you paste? You should try tipping it manually.

Comment: It doesn't involve a windows/mac machine, I just run the first code on Ubuntu's terminal and copy the output with `ctrl+shift+c`, then I paste with `ctrl+shift+v`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you Copy a Windows EOL Char. It does not display in your terminal. Try pasting it in `vi`, and you will see better what's wrong.